# jQuery.ajax - Why does it not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-browser

I just can't get the ajax service to work. A simple class to `$.get("http://google.com")` does not work. Also, this code does not work, too:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>

        $.ajax({
            url:        "http://google.com",
            dataType:   "html",
            success:    function(data, status) {
                console.log("Success:");
                console.log("    Data: " + data);
                console.log("    Status: " + status);
            },
            error:      function(request, status, error) {
                console.log("Error:");
                console.log("    Request: " + request);
                console.log("    Status: " + status);
                console.log("    Error: " + error);
            },
        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

saved in `test.html`.

This is the output on the console:

```
Error:
    Request: [object Object]
    Status: error
    Error:
```

And these are the, I guess, important values of the returned object:

```
readyState          0
responseText        ""
status              0
statusText          "error"
```

Why does the request not work?
Thank you,

Comment: jQuery has problems with cross domain requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use AJAX to access cross-domain scripts like that.  This is because of the [Same Origin Policy](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Same_origin_policy) -- something which has been implemented for security reasons:

> This mechanism bears a particular significance for modern web
>   applications that extensively depend on HTTP cookies to maintain
>   authenticated user sessions, as servers act based on the HTTP cookie
>   information to reveal sensitive information or take state-changing
>   actions.  A strict separation between content provided by unrelated
>   sites must be maintained on client side to prevent the loss of data
>   confidentiality or integrity.

So you have a few options:

1. Just call scripts on your own server
2. Call scripts on your server which can communicate with third-party sites/apps/scripts
3. Use either [JSONP](http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax/) or [XML](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) as a callback format.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a request to another domain due to the same-origin-policy. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more information.

Comment: It's strange though that the exact code does not throw a `XMLHttpRequest cannot load`. When you change the URL it will: http://jsfiddle.net/xEJWc/

Comment: @m90 I would image thats because google sets headers to allow cross domain requests and stackoverflow doesnt

Comment: Hm, the difference is that google.com responds with a "301 Moved permanently" redirection request while stackoverflow.com sends "200 Ok".

Answer (score 1):

You could use JSONP to achieve cross domain communication.

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP

But for plain html you have yo be on the same domain.

```
 $.ajax({
        url:        "http://google.com",
        dataType:   "jsonp",
        success:    function(data, status) {
            console.log("Success:");
            console.log("    Data: " + data);
            console.log("    Status: " + status);
        },
        error:      function(request, status, error) {
            console.log("Error:");
            console.log("    Request: " + request);
            console.log("    Status: " + status);
            console.log("    Error: " + error);
        },
    });
```

EDIT:

But if your URL doesn't return a valid formatted json, your request will fail.
For a working example check:

> http://jsfiddle.net/S3tAR/1/